# How to install ffmpeg for ubuntu using command line?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ffmpeg, apt-get

A lit background...
This is a piece of code in my Dockerfile. I want to deploy my app to google app engine. Somehow I couldn't install ffmpeg.

```
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg
```

This is error log:

```
E: Unable to locate package ffmpeg
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install ffmpeg' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:ef2e6744a171cfb0e8a0ef27f9b9a34970341bfc0c3d401afdeedca72292cf73" failed: exit status 100
```

I found this but it didn't work for me. It complained about **add-apt-repository** is not valid command.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/691109/how-do-i-install-ffmpeg-and-codecs

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use the `add-apt-repository` command you need to:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
```

This is valid for `Ubuntu 14.04` and `16.04`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Or you can use latest official static builds from [here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Comment: I get: #7 0.346 E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a little late but the original answer isn't going to work with Docker.

I made an [image that has ffmpeg included](https://hub.docker.com/r/8675309/ffmpy/) that should get you what you want. However, if you've already got a base image in mind you can add this

```
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y wget nano git build-essential yasm pkg-config

# Compile and install ffmpeg from source
RUN git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg /root/ffmpeg && \
    cd /root/ffmpeg && \
    ./configure --enable-nonfree --disable-shared --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include && \
    make -j8 && make install -j8

# If you want to add some content to this image because the above takes a LONGGG time to build
ARG CACHEBREAK=1
```

That installs ffmpeg from source. If you go this route I would STRONGLY recommend you make a base image which contains this because the image size is over a GB and takes around 5 minutes to build.

Comment: `--enable-nonfree` for `ffmpeg` is only required if including additional components that require it. See `EXTERNAL_LIBRARY_NONFREE_LIST` in `configure` for an up to date list

Comment: Wow. I really appreciate the shared content here.  The content `RUN apt-get...` info posted here was a fail for me.. There were a number of failed `CC` compilations. Lots of red ink.  Error message I see is `Error: Video codec libx264 is not available` ...  sigh.

Comment: definitely recommend this over some RANDOM ass, eventually  unmaintained repository.

Comment: What does `--extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include` mean, and is that assuming that my system is already set up in a certain way?

Answer (score 2):

For me I needed to use the following command:
`apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg`